# Switching images for slide show

Tags: android, slideshow

I am trying to write a program for a slide show.  So far I cannot figure out how to switch between images.  Every time I write a loop, the only image that shows is the last one.  What am I doing wrong
P.S.  I know its bad code, I am playing around with it because I am new to images for android

```
int currentInt;
int imgid[] = { R.drawable.better, R.drawable.beyond_innovation,
        R.drawable.innovation, R.drawable.jobs, R.drawable.no_limits,
        R.drawable.praxis_name, R.drawable.reinvent,
        R.drawable.single_source, R.drawable.toys_to_rockets,
        R.drawable.design };

RefreshHandler refreshHandler = new RefreshHandler();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slideshow);
    this.txtStatus = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.pic_view1);
    this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.slides);
        for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {

            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {

        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are putting all your images into a single `ImageView` and hence only the last one (which is on top) will be displayed.

If you want to make a slideshow, it is easily doable using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). I believe that's exactly the widget people want to use for displaying things using a slide show.